# Updating to php7.1 returns page of echo code instead of layout

Tags: php, cakephp, codeanywhere

[image]

I'm using cakePhp and had to freshly install everything. Before I updated everything was working fine, but then I pulled from the repo and it said i needed 7, so i updated and now get this.

cake and phpinfo say its the same

[image]

then if i try and change the address from / to /phpmyadmin - these are the variants i get

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/bootstrap.php';

use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFactory;

$dispatcher = DispatcherFactory::create();
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    Request::createFromGlobals(),
    new Response()
);
```

and

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;

// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));

// Run the request/response through the application
// and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run());
```

Comment: Check that PHP actually is installed and enabled in Apache, or if you're using Nginx, check that php-fpm is installed and set up in you Nginx config.

Comment: Something went wrong with your update. Most likely your web server configuration has not been updated to use the new PHP interpreter. But there isn't enough information here to know exactly what went wrong.

Comment: `php -v` and (I think) `cake` refer to the PHP CLI. Your web server will not be using that.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable the old version of php that apache is using and enable the new mod.  Check the contents of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.  You should see `php7.1.conf` and `php7.1.load`.  If not try enabling them using `sudo a2enmod php7.1` and `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Also make sure that the old mods are disabled.  If you were upgrading from php 5, you would use `sudo a2dismod php5` and then restart apache.

Comment: My CentOS 7 system doesn't have an /etc/apache2 directory _or_ any file named mods-enabled.  Also no a2enmod.

Comment: @Jeffiekins sorry, this answer is for Ubuntu

Comment: I figured.  Too many people (you have lots of company) don't consider that the most popular _desktop_ Linux isn't the most popular _server_ Linux.